# Checkout to a custom changelist

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to checkout a file directly into a specific pending changelist in Perforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using p4win or p4v, you can use the drag and drop facility to check a file out directly to a preexisting changelist.  from the commandline, you can use `p4 edit` with the `-c [changelist #]` command.

Comment: I'm using the visual client, and the drag-and-drop function is working well. But actually, I'm wondering if there is a way to "Check-Out-Into" instead of "Check-Out-Then-Move".

Comment: I've checked, and you're right. I can checkout the file directly by drag-and-drop'ing it to an existing changelist.

Thanks.